# Configuring QinQ in EX with enterprise style

Tags: juniper, qinq

I'm practicing QinQ with EX boxes. So with downlink and uplink in SP style, that is with flexible vlan tagging and extended vlan bridge, it is working. (https://supportportal.juniper.net/s/article/EX-QFX-How-to-configure-QinQ-using-ELS-on-Junos-OS?language=en_US).

But I was wondering if with EP style, that is uplink is a simple trunk, with unit 0 family eth-switching, QinQ can be supported. Is QinQ supported only with SP style? Or is there a config guide for EP style as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in ELS, Q-inQ is only supported using SP-style.
Older generation non-ELS switches (2200,3200,4200) allowed family ethernet-switching, but that all changed with ELS